# Concrete5 Language-Specific Content for a Block on a Layout Needed

Tags: internationalization, concrete5

I need to be able to make regions of an existing layout into a language-specific block.

There are images/links in the footer of my layout that I'd like to be able to edit for, say the German version of the website, but not for the English version.

How can I accomplish this without having to manually modify and/or link this content each time I want to create a new page for the German version of the website?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about managing sites in multiple languages... but my vague understanding of how it's handled in C5 is that you create different sections of your site for each language (as opposed to having one page serve multiple versions of its content). There is a free addon to manage your site this way: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/internationalization/

I think their theory on this is that most real-world sites eventually require more changes on a per-language basis than "just a link here, just a word there", and in many cases it winds up just being simpler and easier to have separate pages for each. Of course that does present the problem of having to manage 2x or 3x as much content when it actually *is* the same for different languages -- but I think this is what the Internationalization addon I linked to above helps address (it lets you copy pages or entire sections of the site from one place to another and keeps track of which versions are actually the same and keeps those in sync, versus pages that have differences on them, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your response Jordan. I am trying to do something a little more specific, however. I need to be able to have a block (a better term may be a "page") of content that is editable and the contents of said block/page are always populated into a certain region of a "Page Type" whenever that Page Type is created. The key problem is having that content be language-specific. Imagine a footer that is very basic including only a copyright notice, but I need a copyright notice in German and one in English, and that to only change depending on which language "Content Area" the user is in.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about the term "block" versus "page"? These are 2 distinct things in Concrete5 and depending on which one you actually mean, that would require a completely different solution. A "block" is one piece of content on a page, and a page is an entire page (that contains several blocks). Or perhaps you mean an "area", which is several blocks that make up a portion of a page (for example, when you add blocks to a page and click "Add to Main", or "Add to Sidebar" -- Main and Sidebar are two different areas)?